# Pythonでの正規表現（漢字文字列の抽出）を使った実行結果が予期しないものになりました。

Tags: python, 正規表現

以下のプログラムにおいて、結果をコード中のコメント部分に書きました。
このプログラムは、すべての漢字文字列を抽出するためのものですが、どういうわけか、「私」と「首都」だけが取り出せません。

特定の単語が抽出できないわけはないので、困っています。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import re 

print(re.findall('[亜-熙]+', '私の名前は堀内です。'))   #  --> ['名前', '堀内']
print(re.findall('[亜-熙]+', '君の名前は堀内です。'))   #  --> ['君', '名前', '堀内']
print(re.findall('[亜-熙]+', '君の私は堀内です。'))     #  --> ['君', '堀内']
print(re.findall('[亜-熙]+', '私の私は私です。'))       #  --> []
print(re.findall('[亜-熙]+', '日本の首都は東京です。')) #  --> ['日本', '東京']
print(re.findall('[亜-熙]+', '首都の首都は首都です。')) #  --> []
```

Comment: どういう意図で `[亜-熙]` と書きましたか?

Comment: 「亜」の Unicode コードポイントは `U+4E9C`, 「熙」は `U+7199` です。一方、「首」は `U+9996`「都」は `U+90fd` なので範囲外になります。また、「私」は `U+79c1` なので、こちらも範囲外です。

Comment: ちなみに、[regex · PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) は Unicode プロパティに対応しているので、`import regex as re` としてインポートして、`re.findall(r'\p{Han}+', '首都の首都は首都です。')` などとします。

Comment: 質問者です。よくわかりました。Unicodeが制定される以前に得た知識でした。

Answer (score 2):

- `亜` のコードポイントが U+4E9C
- `熙` のコードポイントが U+7199
- `私` `首` `都` が U+79C1 U+9996 U+90FD

ですので、当然マッチしません。

すべての漢字にマッチさせるには `\p{Han}` と書くのが簡単なのですが、Python 標準の `re` ではこの表記に対応していません。対応している他の Python 用正規表現エンジンは存在はしているようです。

どうしても`re`でやる必要があるなら、対応させたいコードポイントを調べて書き下すしかないと思います。例えば「CJK統合漢字だけマッチすればよい」という条件であるなら、`[\u4E00-\u9FFF]` でいいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

`[一-龥]`で表示されます。
Unicodeブロックの範囲を指定する必要があります。
Shift_JISなどの`[亜-熙]'の範囲には含まれていないためです。

[image]

Comment: ググってみましたら、以下の方法が見つかりました。

Comment: [\x{2E80}-\x{2FDF}々〇〻\x{3400}-\x{4DBF}\x{4E00}-\x{9FFF}\x{F900}-\x{FAFF}\x{20000}-\x{3FFFF}]　のパターンです。これでやってみます。

Comment: 回答について、文字の情報は画像ではなく文字のまま投稿してください。